# Easy way to send a signal to direct children only?

Tags: unix, signals

Is there an easy way to signal only direct children of a process? That is, if A spawns B1 and B2, and the B's spawn C's, can A easily signal just the B's? It seems like it should be relatively simple, but I can't find anything, and I'd rather not do anything complicated if I don't have to.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't want to or can't change the process groups of the grandchildren, an easy way is just to maintain a list of the B processes.

Comment: I suppose that would probably be the easiest way. I had hoped there was something similar to process groups that would work, but I suppose there probably isn't.